# '80 sci-fi horror movie featuring an incorporeal alien that passes from human body to body like electricity

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

The movie begins with a truck transporting a metal coffin with a child inside being cryopreserved. An accident follows and the refrigeration system is damaged releasing an incorporeal alien from its prison. The alien passes from human body to human body like electricity. A couple chases the alien until it tries to escape on a ship that is buried under the city for thousands of years. In the end, the couple enters the ship and damages it, but the alien manages to escape with the ship cruising through the atmosphere heavily damaged. There is another scene where a man types on a very futuristic keyboard embedded within a glass table.